# Undefined save method when using dynamic finders in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, rake, dynamic-finders

I have a simple rake task importing records from a CSV file and saving them into the database.

```
require 'csv'

namespace :import do
  task :items => :environment do

  CSV.foreach(Rails.root.to_s + '/public/data/items.csv', :headers => true) do |row|

   @item_id = row[1]

   if item_id
    i = Item.find_or_create_by_item_id(@item_id)
    i.update_attributes(
      :item_id     => @item_id,
      :category    => row[2],
      :price       => row[3],
    )
    i.save
   end

  end

 end
end
```

When I run it I get the following error.

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `save' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
```

This was working fine and I have other rake tasks using dynamic finders on the same model in the same way which work fine. I can't figure out what changed or what is causing this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `if item_id`. Should that be `@item_id`? Also, `update_attributes` automatically saves the record. You don't need to call `save()`. Remove that line and see if that gets rid of the error.

As a side note, why do you have an attribute for Item called `item_id`? It would be a lot better just to use `id` unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: Sorry the item_id/@item_id was a typo in me adding the code to StackOveflow.